# How can I determine whether a nested class is static in a Groovy AST transformation?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree, inner-classes

In an AST transformation, I am trying to detect whether a class `Foo` has nested classes and, if so, whether they are static or inner classes:

```
@MyTransform
class Foo {
  static class A {}
  class B {}
}
```

When I examine `fooCn.innerClasses`, both `Foo$A` and `Foo$B` are listed. `ClassNode` includes a method called `isStaticClass`, but by the Javadoc, this only tells me whether a nested class is declared *within a static method* (as a *local* class), not whether it is a "static class" by the JLS definition. Both `a.staticClass` and `b.staticClass` return `false`, and both `a` and `b` return `Foo` for `outerClass`.

How can I inspect the class nodes for `Foo$A` and `Foo$B` and determine that `Foo$A` is a static nested class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ClassNode` representing each class has a property `modifiers` containing the modifier flags for the class; bit 4 (value 8) is defined as the `STATIC` modifier. The utility method `java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(classNode.modifiers)` will indicate whether the class is static nested or inner.

Comment: I am posting this answer because, based on my experimentation, this seems to work, but I am not marking it as accepted for a little while in case someone with better knowledge of the Groovy compiler API has a better solution.

Comment: You’re correct. Check the modifiers. The staticClass flag is a historical remnant that you likely won’t need to bother with.

Comment: ClassNodeUtils#isInnerClass shows checking for non-static.